# Why the need to show well definedness for the following case of restriction maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, morphism

The following is based on an exercise from the book $linear algebra and geometry" by Leung.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

Show that if the diagram of linear spaces and linear transformations

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X  \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y \\
\end{array},\quad (1)$$

is commutative, then the linear transformations a and d define linear transformations $\text{ker }b  \to  \text{ker }c$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

To show the existence of the linear transformation, i extend the commutative diagram like below with the top edge of the extended commutative diagram to be the restriced map $a|_{\text{ker }b}:\text{ker }b  \to  \text{ker }c$.

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{ker }b & \xrightarrow{a|_{\text{ker }b}} & \text{ker }c  \\
i_b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow i_c   \\
X' & \xrightarrow{a} & X  \\
b\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow c   \\
Y' & \xrightarrow{d} & Y \\
\end{array},\quad (2)$$

I can then employ the universal property of the kernel to show existence.  What I don' t understand is why I need to show the map $a|_{\text{ker }b}$ is well defined.  I thought if I have a map $f:X\to Y$, unless the domain $X$ consists of cosets, then I really don't have to show the function is well defined.  As the map $a|_{\text{ker }b}$ is only a restriction map.  I don't recall when learning about restriction and extension maps, I need to show that they are well dedined.  Can someone provide me with some clarification on thi smatter please.

Thank you in advance.